# Pressure unit computation (feet of mercury, but applies also to foot of water..)

Tags: pressure, units, unit-conversion

Grr this question makes me crazy.

Here you can see that ftHg = 13595.1 kg/m3 × 1 ft × ɡ0 = ≈ 4.063666×104 Pa. (= 40636.664 Pa)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_units (**Pressure or mechanical stress**)

I guess that 13595.1 is density of mercury, but have no idea what is calculated in the formula, why and how.

Force of density of 1 kg of mercury in m3 from height of 1 ft (1d unit) times some gravity constant?

As it should be some (atmospheric - or probably any) pressure unit maybe it makes sense that lenght unit (feet), but why the gravity constant?

If i divide 40636.664 / 13595.1 and suppose that ft is 1, that g0 should be 2.989066943236902, but can't make it working.

Please explain it very foolproof :D Thanks.

Comment: The calculation is done this way because the equation for pressure in a static fluid is $P = \rho g h$

Answer (score 2):

What you're after is the force per unit area exerted by a layer of mercury a foot deep, at the Earth's surface.  Each square meter of the surface has a force acting on it corresponding to the mass of mercury above it.  That mass is the density of mercury (in $\mathrm{kg/m^3}$) times the depth, $1\mathrm{ft} = 381/1250\,\mathrm{m}$, times the acceleration due to gravity at the surface, $g_0=9.8\,\mathrm{ms^{-2}}$.  So that's

$$
\begin{align}
13595.1\,\mathrm{\frac{kg}{m^3}}\times \frac{381}{1250}\,\mathrm{m}
\times 9.8\,\mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}} &\approx 4.04\times 10^4\,\mathrm{\frac{kg}{m\, s^2}}\\
&\approx 4.04\times 10^4\mathrm{Pa}
\end{align}$$

The last line is because $1\,\mathrm{N}$ is the force required to accelerate $1\,\mathrm{kg}$ by $1\,\mathrm{ms^{-2}}$, or in other words $1\,\mathrm{N} = 1\,\mathrm{kg\,m\,s^{-2}}$, and $1\,\mathrm{Pa}$ is $1\,\mathrm{N}$ per square meter or $1\,\mathrm{kg\,m^{-1}\,s^{-2}}$.